# Webpack on browser

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I am trying to run some javascript code on a browser or on a server.
That includes the ES 6 yarn package and node.js. When I run the command from the terminal it launches a local server on a browser and everything works fine.

But if I try to run the HTML file from the folder or uploading the files onto a server, it doesn't work and it doesn't recognize any of the code I wrote.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you something like `Babel` in your terminal step somewhere that *transpiles* your javascript code and launches a browser to serve the code in memory.

In order to have it work in an html file or on your server, you'll have to `transpile` your  javascript code to use in HTML files.

Browsers do not currently understand all ES6 syntax, almost any ES6 javascript code needs to be transpiled for the browser as of today.

Comment: would you mind to explain me on how to transpile it?

Comment: You'll need to transpile the html file using webpack/babel, which isn't too hard to configure with a client framework, like Express.